# Chrome has “Failed to load PDF document” error message when call pdf from url in PHP. But works in Firefox and Edge

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf

I want to open a pdf file from URL from a REST service in my browser, using PHP, but the file doesn't open. Chrome said, "Failed to load PDF document". But works correctly in Firefox and Edge.

This is my print.php

```
<?php

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

$data = ...; //definition of my json object

$baseUrl = 'http://www.website.com:8080/report/api/something/';
$newUrl = $baseUrl .'path';

$additional_headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

echo  $server_output;

?>
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed, that this happens when the amount of records in my report exceeds a certain amount (always in chrome, other browsers work perfectly). But I still can not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution!!!

First of all, I change my CURL call, changed the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` then, using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to call my PHP page, I noticed the content of the result was look like this:

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in
<b>Unknown</b> on line
<b>0</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>Unknown</b> on line
<b>0</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>4</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>4</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>5</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>24</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\print.php</b> on line
<b>77</b>
<br />
%PDF-1.5
%����
3 0 obj<
</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 515/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Width 545/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 47996>>stream
���� ...........................................
```

The PDF it's correctly downloaded from the REST service, but PHP show too many errors for that reason Chrome can't open the PDF File (and for that reason too, when the data count of my PDF File was <= 5 rows was shown in Chrome, because the lower the number of records, the lower the amount of warning that PHP launched). To solve this I put `error_reporting(0)` of the top of my PHP file (**Obviously is better fixing the warnings**):

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // to prevent show warning or errors, use carefully

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
...
```

Then, when I execute my PHP page again the content of the page if only the PDF file

```
%PDF-1.5
%����
3 0 obj<
</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 515/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Width 545/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 47996>>stream
���� ...........................................
```

Comment: The goal of this is to show other people, where to look for the problem. Not what is the best practice. I know my recommendation isn't the best solution and it's the worst practice.